# Deletion of Managed Package in Dev Org

Tags: managed-package, delete

I have created a managed package in my Dev Org and that package has a listing on the Partner Org. Now the requirements have changed so I have removed the app from my listings. Now I want to delete the managed package present in my Dev Org but when I go to...

> Create > Package > GIS (Package Name) > Delete

... It shows the following error:

> "This Package cannot be deleted because it has the following uploaded versions:
>
> Version Number: 1.0
>
> Version Name: Winter 2016

Comment: have you uninstalled from your partner org or wherever you have installed this package?

Comment: I have uninstalled it every where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to log a ticket with salesforce, as you cannot deprecate the latest version of the managed package.
Please use this link if you want to learn more about the packages:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_uploads.htm&language=en_US